# read value file in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, file-io, matrix

Currently I am using read comma-separated value (CSV) file which is `csvread` in my code. what if I want to read value row by row, which my value is not seperated by comma?

This is my code for save data:

```
%% Save data to .txt
fid=fopen('MyFile1.txt','w');
fprintf(fid, '%f \n', AngleValue');
fclose(fid);
```

This is the save values

[image]

Then I run a code using csvread

```
I = csvread('MyFile1.txt');
```

but I got an error. can anyone give an idea, probably I should change how I save my data or how can I read the data row by row. Thanks

Comment: what error exactly are you recieving?

Comment: specify the error which you got during using csvread

Comment: the error quiet complicated to be stated since at the beginning, i already use wrong function which is csvread. i know that i must change that only thing so that the other whole code can function properly. thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are other alternatives to `csvread`. Try [`dlmread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) instead

```
I = dlmread('MyFile.txt');
```

---

A more general approach,
Why are you writing `AngleValue` as text files? Why not use [`save`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) and [`load`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html) in a more Matlab-ish fashion? read and write in binary format, tailored for Matlab use?

```
 save('MyFile.mat','AngleValue'); %// save to binary Mat file
```

Once you saved the variable, you can read it:

```
 load('MyFile.mat'); %// that's it!
```

Comment: brilliant idea. but i'm having problem with my program if i'm using .mat i still need to stick using csvread, otherwise i have to edit some of my current code. thanks btw

Answer (score 0):

use

```
A = fscanf(fileID,formatSpec)
```

more [info](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I found out that i just have to put coma (,) when i fprintf my saved data.

My previous code:

```
fprintf(fid, '%f \n', AngleValue');
```

My corrected code:

```
fprintf(fid, '%f,', AngleValue');
```

So now i can use csvread in my program.

Comment: and if you ommit the space at the end of the line: `fprintf(fid, '%f\n', AngleValue.');`?